# What's the limitations of PDO named arguments

Tags: pdo

Using prepared statements with PDO, I understand it as there's two paths,
either `?` or `:name`.

What are the limitations regarding the named parameters? White spaces? Non ASCII-chars?

(I'm well acquainted with the hell of non-ASCII in field names. So please stick to the topic.)

Answer (score 0):

Those are tokens. Limits are probably A-Z, 0-9 characters, not starting with 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

From that [switch starting on the line of 304](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#L304) I would say it is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`